# Composer won't autoload

Tags: php, composer-php

I've got a new project that I'm trying to stand up with Composer from the start, [I'm a very late adopter] but autoloading *will not work*, I can't figure out why, and it's driving me nuts.

This is literally it for the project right now: [excluding /vendor/]

```
/
    lib/
        Client.php
    composer.json
    test.php
```

composer.json

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-0": {
            "Openstack\\": "lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

lib/Client.php

```
<?php
namespace Openstack;

class Client {
    public function __construct() {
        echo "hello world";
    }
}
```

test.php

```
<?php
require('vendor/autoload.php');
$foo = new Openstack\Client();
```

Trying to run test.php gives me:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Openstack\Client' not found
```

Even though:

```
# grep -r Openstack vendor/composer/
vendor/composer/autoload_namespaces.php:    'Openstack' => array($baseDir . '/lib'),
```

What does this thing want of me?!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When you use psr-0, you need to have a directory for each namespace level. So your directory structure needs to be this:

```
/
    lib/
        Openstack/
            Client.php
    composer.json
    test.php
```

Alternatively, you can use psr-4 in your `composer.json`.

```
{
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "Openstack\\": "lib/"
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: It worth mentioning that `PSR-0` is marked as deprecated as of October 2014

Comment: That does the trick! However, the next problem is `use \Openstack; $foo = new Client();` brings back the 'Class not found' error. :/

Comment: @Sammitch That's not how PHP namespaces work. You need to `use` the entire class name `use Openstack\Client;`